# Product of two ODE is equivalent to two Cauchy problems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Why is (and is it true that) solving $q'(t)(4q'(t)+q(t))=0$ equivalent to solving $\begin{cases} q'(t)=0 \\ q(0)=1 \end{cases}$ and $\begin{cases} 4q'(t)+q(t)=0 \\ q(0)=1 \end{cases}$?

I get the first equations but where do the initial conditions $q(0)=1$ come from?

Comment: both ODEs are linear, so the initial data isn't so important

Comment: @CalvinKhor So it has only been put there to make it "easier" and find one particular solution? But why is "both ODEs are linear" the reason? In which cases wouldn't it work to randomly choose an initial condition?

Comment: Because if you want to solve with $q(0) = k\neq 1$ just take $kq$ where $q$ is the solution for $q(0)=1$. This trick needs linearity

Comment: Would you write it as an answer so I can accept it? Though I still don't quite understand "linearity" of **what** (of the ODE, but it isn't a transformation, so the real question is "linearity of **what** transformation?") but I think the reason is just some lack of **words** because it makes sense anyway.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not true as stated. For example, the function $q(t) = 4$ satisfies the first differential equation, but satisfies neither of the latter initial value problems. If the ODE weas originally supposed to be
$$q'(t)(4q'(t) + q(t)) = 0, \quad q(0) = 1,$$
then this conclusion would indeed follow.

---

Just a heads up: there is a subtle issue with taking
$$q'(t)(4q'(t) + q(t)) = 0 \tag{1}$$
for all $t$ and concluding that
$$q'(t) = 0 \tag{2}$$
for all $t$, or
$$q'(t)(4q'(t) + q(t)) = 0 \tag{3}$$
for all $t$.

If $(1)$ holds for every value of $t$, then for every value of $t$, $(2)$ or $(3)$ holds, but which of the two options holds may change with $t$. For example, it could be (prima facie) that $(2)$ holds for $t = -5$, but not for $t = 2$ (in which case $(3)$ holds). So long as each $t$ satisfies one of the differential equations, the original equation will be satisfied.

In this particular case, it actually happens that $(2)$ holds for all $t$, or $(3)$ holds for all $t$, but we need a little more work. Note that the general solution for $(2)$ (holding for all $t$) is $q(t) = A$, i.e. constant functions. The general solution to $(3)$ (for all $t$) is $q(t) = Be^{-t/4}$.

Using a bit of analysis, under the assumption that neither $(1)$ nor $(2)$ holds in every case, we can find a point $t_0$ which satisfies both conditions at the same time. This means that $q'(t_0) = 0$ from $(1)$, and from $(2)$, $q(t_0) = 0$. Some more analysis reveals that the only such solution would be $q(t) = 0$ for all $t$, i.e. the constant solution that satisfies $(1)$ and $(2)$ simultaneously for all $t$. This contradicts our assumption.

As an example where this could go wrong, consider the ODE $q'''(t)q'(t) = 0$. Note that
$$q(t) = \begin{cases} x^2 & \text{if } x \ge 0 \\ 0 & \text{if } x < 0 \end{cases}$$
is a solution to the given ODE, but satisfies neither $q'(t) = 0$ or $q'''(t) = 0$.